# Apache NIFi MergeContent processor - set demarcator as new line

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to use MergeContent processor to merge tweets to bulk insert into Elasticsearch index. For this I need command and tweets (each) to be separated by \n. 
This is how it should look like

```
{ action: { metadata }}\n
{ request body        }\n
```

Which will be

```
{ “index”}
{ tweet1 }
{ tweet2 }
```

When I put \n as separator the processor actually adds \n as a string instead of new line separator. Is it possible to make it actual new line?
Also is it possible to leave or make footer empty?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are correct in that it takes the literal representation of what is entered.  There are two ways to handle this:

1. With delimiter strategy of 'Text': Hit shift + enter to provide a new line
2. With delimiter strategy of 'Filename': Provide a path to a file that is only a newline character

With regards to your question on leaving the footer empty, it should work as you anticipate for the Merge Format of 'Binary Concatenation.' Making a quick test flow, I have verified this, but please let us know if it is not working for your particular configuration.

Comment: NiFi 0.4.0 just released and now empty header, footer and detonator issue fixed.

Comment: Thanks @Apiri.. your comment saved  my time