# Apache NiFi: How to set space (new line) in MergeContent demarcator?

Tags: apache-nifi

In my NiFi flow I have MergeContent processor.

This processor consumes some data from different groups.

I need to set demarcator to make a new line after every merge.

Now output looks like this:

```
Table ERR$_TABLE_NAME: 347 errors Table ERR$_TABLE_NAME2: 432 errors Table ERR$_TABLE_NAME3: 33 errors
```

But I would like it to look like this:

```
Table ERR$_TABLE_NAME1: 347 errors
Table ERR$_TABLE_NAME2: 432 errors
Table ERR$_TABLE_NAME3: 33 errors
```

To put it simply, I need to add /n after every line.

Now my demarcator parameter have this code:

```
${literal('&#10;'):unescapeXml()}
```

What do I need to add to go to a new line after every merge?

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34257810/3810086

Comment: @tonykoval thanks, this help for now. I think this is best solution yet, so I will use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution that I found for now is to press combination of shift and enter to provide a new line.